# If I Don't Use "required" Tag in TextBox or Input, My Design Is Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, textbox

I'm facing a strange error.

This is my search text: `<asp:TextBox ID="productsearch" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="What are you looking for" required="reqired"></asp:TextBox>`

And this is my e-mail text: `<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail Adress" required>`

when I try to delete the required part, the following menu is not working (a menu with a pop-up to the left):

```
<a href="#" class="sidemenu-btn" title="Menu Toggle">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</a>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: first of all there's typo on your required attribute. you typed it 'reqired'

Comment: when using 'required', asp injects more javascript in your page in order to cover that functionality. maybe your menu depends on some of that javascript